# How can I get rid of of Wine's Steam icon in the Dash?

Tags: unity, wine, steam

Using Ubuntu 13.04:

I decided it was time to uninstall the Windows version of Steam I was running through Wine. So I used Wine's uninstall applications function to remove it and all its files. Then I used Ubuntu's software centre to uninstall Wine and the Windows compatibility layer.

The problem is that, in Unity, if I search 'Steam', the image for the Windows version still appears.

- Click it, nothing happens.
- Drag to desktop and delete, nothing happens.
- Used the command line to remove and then purge Steam. On the Desktop, no result.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

Browse to `/usr/share/applications`, find file called "Steam" and delete it.
If it is not there look for it under `~/.local/share/applications/` (~ means your home folder).

Comment: No dice, only version of Steam in there is the Native Linux client, which I don't want to delete. No files of the Wine Windows client to be found, but it's still showing if I search Unity.

Comment: Sounds bad. Is there maybe "wine" folder under ~/.local/share/applications?

Comment: @Tuxest It's bad practice to ask for upvotes on the Stackexchange network. I did upvote your answer, but strictly for its merit and not your remark.

Comment: @Glutanimate. I know it is a bad practice and I have done this with few of my answers lately as an experiment. I just wanted to test whether it makes any difference as I am quite sure that most of the people who use this site (I mean specifically askubuntu and not Stackexchange network in general) have no clue about what these arrows are for.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rm -r ~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/Steam`

At least with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.04, the `wine` package from the *universe* repository and the latest Steam installer, the `.desktop` files are put there.